# How to fix the warning: "RPMDB altered outside of yum"?

Tags: redhat, yum, rhn

I have a RHEL 6 system, that I primarily manage through RHN Satellite.  Recently I scheduled some updates through Satellite and received a response that the updates had failed.  I ssh'd into the system to investigate, and saw this warning when running `yum`:

```
Warning: RPMDB altered outside of yum.
```

How do I fix this warning?

Comment: Stop installing and removing packages with the rpm command and stick to yum.

Comment: yum clean all , then next time you use yum warning should not appear or you can try " yum history sync"

Comment: See https://superuser.com/questions/558200/is-it-possible-to-use-yum-to-install-a-rpm-file-in-red-hat-linux about installing RPMs with yum

Answer (score 33):

As noted [by arana](https://serverfault.com/users/164826/arana) and supported by [RHEL documentation](https://access.redhat.com/documentation/en-us/red_hat_enterprise_linux/7/html/system_administrators_guide/sect-yum-transaction_history), another command (that worked in my situation) is:

```
yum history sync
```

It will iterate through the installed RPMs and synchronize the rpm & yumdb databases.

Answer (score 6):

As mentioned in the comments, this is a harmless warning that informs you that a package has been installed or removed directly using the `rpm` command instead of `yum`. The difference is that `yum` is smarter in automatically resolving dependencies, and it is the default way of keeping the package-management DB on your system up-to-date (hence the warning).

See [Execution of yum leads to "Warning: RPMDB altered outside of yum."](https://access.redhat.com/solutions/62321) for an official explanation of the message on the Red Hat Customer Portal.

To get rid of the warning, run:

```
# yum history new
```

See also [yum or rpm](https://access.redhat.com/discussions/1247533), which contains further explanations and links to Red Hat documentation about both Yum and RPM.

Comment: that DID solve the problem, but it also deletes the history.

Comment: This part is confusing as written because RPM also does both of those things: “The difference is that yum automatically resolves dependencies for you and keeps the package-management DB on your system up-to-date.”

The difference is that YUM has a more advanced resolution system which can avoid edge cases such as when a dependency isn't in the same repository.

Comment: Thanks @chris-adams. I updated the answer to be more specific.